# Digit placement and counting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, counting, brute-force

I found a Microsoft interview question in [this blog](http://zianet.dk/blog/2007/02/21/my-job-interview-at-microsoft-development-center-copenhagen-mdcc/)

I cutted out the question for you:

> “This is a sentence that contains
>   _ 0
>   _ 1
>   _ 2
>   _ 3
>   _ 4
>   _ 5
>   _ 6
>   _ 7
>   _ 8
>   _ 9 digits” Make it logically true. So the point is that where there’s an underscore you need to put a single digit so that the entire
>   sentence becomes true. Ie, there are 1 0, 5 1′s, etc. in the string.

I couldn't find an answer on the net. We brute forced it manually with my roommate =) and found one solution as:

> 1 0, 7 1, 3 2, 2 3, 1 4, 1 5, 1 6, 2 7, 1 8, 1 9

How would you approach this problem as a programming question? How would you do a brute force implementation? Is there a clever way of solving this? Are there different solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The brute force solution is fairly easy.

Try each possible number of occurrences for each character. Separate the target number of occurrences from the actual number of occurrences and compare the two.

```
initialize a 'target' array to the target number of occurrences of each character
  (initial values don't matter - they are assigned before being checked)

initialize an 'occurrences' array to the actual number of occurrences
  (initial values are all 1's in this case)

call bruteForce(0)

bruteForce(value)
  if value > greatest value
    check data and exit is successful
  for i = 1:9
    target[value] = i
    // fail early - not strictly necessary, but should help running time
    if value >= i && occurrences[i] + 1 > target[i]
      continue
    occurrences[i]++
    // recurse
    bruteForce(value + 1)
    occurrences[i]--
```

[Java live demo](https://ideone.com/H0G37i).